# NiFi - data stuck in queues when load balancing is used

Tags: apache-nifi

In Apache NiFi, dockerized version 1.15, a cluster of 3 NiFi nodes is created. When load balancing is used via default port 6342, flow files get stuck in some of the queues, in the queue in which load balancing is enabled. But, when "List queue" is tried, the message "The queue has no FlowFiles." is issued:

The part of the NiFi processor group where the issue happens:

[image: The part of NiFi processor group where the issue happens]

Configuration of NiFi queue in which flow files seem to be stuck:

[image: Configuration of NiFi queue in which flow files seem to be stuck]

[image]

Another problem, maybe not related, is that after this happens, some of the flow files reach the subsequent NiFi processors, but get stuck before the MergeContent processors. This time, the queues can be listed:

The part of code when the second issue occurs:

[The part of code when the second issue occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ef9Q.png)

[image: The part of code when the second issue occurs_02]

The configuration of the queue:

[image: The configuration of the queue]

The listing of the FlowFiles in the queue:

[image: The listing of the FlowFiles in the queue]

The MergeContent processor configuration. The parameter "max_num_for_merge_smxs" is set to 100:

[image: The MergeContent processor configuration]

Load balancing is used because data are gathered from the SFTP server, and that processor runs only on the Primary node.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Edited:

I put the load-balancing queues between the ConsumeMQTT (working on the Primary node only) and UpdataAttribute processors, but Flow files are seemingly staying in the load-balancing queue, but when the listing is done, the message is "The queue has no FlowFiles.". Please check:

Changed position of the load-balancing queue:

[image: Changed position of the load-balancing queue]

The message that there are no flow files in the queues:

[image: Message that there are no flow files in the queus]

Take notice that the processors before and after the queue are stopped while doing "List queue".

Edit 2:

I changed the configuration in the nifi.properties to the following:

```
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=20
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=60
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec
```

I also restarted the NiFi containers, so I will monitor the behaviour. For now, there are no stuck Flow files in the load-balancing queues, they go to the processor that follows the queue.

Comment: Please share a complete view of your - i.e. What is before & after the queues in which flowfiles are stuck

Comment: I changed the first picture to show the flow for the first case, when the issue is with the load balancing queues, and added the image of flow when the second issue happens, before the MergeContent processor. For the second issue, I hope that you are right, I will check if there are more than 300 flow files in the queues.

Comment: In some queues there are more than 3000 flow files, but they are not entering the MergeContent processor.

Comment: Have you tried putting a processor (UpdateAttribute) between the input ports and the merge processors? That should help to identify whether it has to do with loadbalancing or the merge processors. Also, there's a red warning about the threads on your merge process group. Is some processor stuck trying to terminate?

Comment: Yes, I tried putting the load-balancing queue before the UpdateAttribute processor, please check the edited part of the question. Red warnings do not have any connection to the problem, I checked.

Comment: I've seen some ghost flowfiles in queues even on a single node, but that was during development, with processors hanging and us terminating them. A restart of NiFi would clear all the ghosts then. I will tak your word for it that terminated threads are not the cause. Next suspect would be the loadbalancing connections timing out or being starved of threads. Do the docker containers have enough vCPU assigned to handle the configured threads?

Comment: @Cyrus I changed the configuration for load balancing in the nifi.properties files, please check the second edit of the question. I also restarted the containers with NiFi, and all the flow files in queues are gone. Also, for now, it seems that messages do not get stuck in the load-balancing queue, but I will monitor the situation and let you know if the error happens. Thank you very much for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

"The queue has no FlowFiles" is normal behaviour of a queue that is feeding into a Merge - the flowfiles are pending to be merged.

The most likely cause of them being "stuck" before a Merge is that you have Round Robin distributed the FlowFiles across many nodes, and then you are setting a Minimum count on the Merge. This minimum is *per node* and there are not enough FlowFiles on each node to hit the Minimum, so they are stuck waiting for more FlowFiles to trigger the Merge.

-- Edit

"The queue has no FlowFiles" is also expected on a queue that is active - in your flow, the load balancing queue is drained immediately into the output queue of your `merge` PGs Input port - so there are no FFs sitting around in the load balancing queue. If you were to STOP the Input ports inside the `merge` PG, you should be able to list them on the LB queue.

It sounds like you are doing GetSFTP (Primary) and then distributing the files. The better approach would be to use ListSFTP (Primary) -> Load Balance -> FetchSFTP - this would avoid shuffling large files, and would instead load balance the file names between all nodes, with each node then fetching a subset of the files.

Secondly, I would review your Merge config - you have a parameter `#{max_num_for_merge_xmsx}` defined, but this set in the **Minimum** Number of Entries for the Merge - so you are telling Merge to only ever merge when *at least* `#{max_num_for_merge_xmsx}` amount of FlowFiles is reached.

Comment: Before the MergeContent, there ARE flow files in the queue and they can be listed. But before that, in the queue where the load balancing happens, in some cases it is shown that thousands of flow files exist, but when they are listed, it is shown "The queue has no FlowFiles.". If you need more explanation, please let me know.

Comment: @coding what is `#{max_num_for_merge_xmsx}` set to?

Comment: As it is written in the question, ```#{max_num_for_merge_xmsx}``` is set to 100

Comment: Ok, and if you lower it to, say, 5 - do files move or remain stuck?

Comment: Yes, I tried to lower the limit, but with no success. Please check the edited part of the question, it is shown that when the load-balancing queue is moved between the other two processors, the problem persists. Thank you.

Comment: @coding can you check nifi-app.log for any errors? Can you also try restarting nifi  when there are FFs 'stuck' in the queues? Do they remain stuck in the queues after the restart?

Comment: I restarted the NiFi container, and the FF are gone, but I do not know if it solves the issue. Please check Edit 2 of the question.

Comment: Can you stop the flow after the Merge and run your data through again? Does the output of the Merge actually contain all of the data you expect? I want to see if the FFs stuck in the LB are actually stuck there, as in the data has not been processed, or if they have actually been processed and the UI is just showing you the wrong thing

Comment: As I said, now there are no stuck FF in the load balancing queue, everything is working. I hope that it is because of the new configuration, but I will monitor the state.